# Difference between array and malloc

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 2

int main(void)
{

    char num1[LEN],num2[LEN];   //works fine with
                                //char *num1= malloc(LEN), *num2= malloc(LEN);
    int number1,number2;
    int sum;

    printf("first integer to add = ");
    scanf("%s",num1);

    printf("second integer to add = ");
    scanf("%s",num2);

    //adds integers
    number1= atoi(num1);
    number2= atoi(num2);
    sum = number1 + number2;

    //prints sum
    printf("Sum of %d and %d = %d \n",number1, number2, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output :

```
first integer to add = 15
second integer to add = 12
Sum of 0 and 12 = 12
```

*Why it is taking `0` instead of first variable `15` ?*

Could not understand why this is happening.

It is working fine if I am using

```
char *num1= malloc(LEN), *num2= malloc(LEN);
```

instead of

```
char num1[LEN],num2[LEN];
```

But it should work fine with this.

Edited :

Yes, it worked for `LEN 3` but why it showed this *undefined behaviour*. I mean not working with the `normal arrays` and working with `malloc`. Now I got that it should not work with `malloc` also. But why it worked for me, please be specific so that I can debug more accurately ?

Is there any issue with my system or compiler or IDE ?

Please explain a bit more as it will be helpful or provide any links to resources. Because I don't want to be *unlucky* anymore.

Comment: Did you know you can `scanf` integer values and thus not need to use `atoi`?

Comment: Maybe a bug in atoi, because of the possible memory misalignment (ie not at a good 32 bit start address) of num1? Just a guess

Comment: Nice well presented first question.  Note: `num1` is too small to hold "15" which needs 3 `char`.

Comment: "why it showed this *undefined behaviour*. I mean not working with the normal arrays and working with malloc." This is, sadly, the very *definition* of undefined behaviour: it may appear to work, it may appear to not work, it may break silently hours later when your program is off doing something totally unrelated. You cannot, and should not, ever rely on "undefined behaviour" to be consistent, predictable, nor sane. Explanations exist, but the best explanation is simply to avoid UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEN` is defined as 2. You left no room for a null terminator. In the array case you would overrun the array end and damage your stack. In the `malloc` case you would overrun your heap and potentially damage the `malloc` structures.

Both are undefined behaviour. You are unlucky that your code works at all: if you were "lucky", your program would decide to crash in every case just to show you that you were triggering undefined behaviour. Unfortunately that's not how undefined behaviour works, so as a C programmer, you just have to be defensive and avoid entering into undefined behaviour situations.

Why are you using strings, anyway? Just use `scanf("%d", &number1)` and you can avoid all of this.

Comment: @SachinPanwar: It **doesn't**. You are exceptionally unlucky that it appeared to work, because it meant that you didn't find out that it **does not work in general**.

Comment: (There is a technical explanation, which is that most `malloc` implementations round the allocation up to at least a multiple of 4 bytes, and frequently up to 16 bytes; consequently, `malloc(2)` usually returns **up to** 16 bytes of usable space. But if you're running on an embedded system, it may very well decide that you get exactly two bytes of usable space, and then your program explodes (possibly literally).)

Comment: It "worked" because `malloc()` typically allocates in block of memory (say 16 bytes chunks or more), so if you ask for 2 you got more.  It is **TERRIBLE** practice to depend on this 'slop space', because one day it won't be there.   Don't do that.

Comment: @nneonneo: Thankyou so much for this explanation. And I got it before that it should not work fine I just want to know why it worked.

Comment: @JohnHascall: Thanks for your explanation and I will remember not to use `malloc()` like this.

Comment: Please tell me that why it is accepting second value `12` as it should not accept both the values.

Comment: I have no idea. Something about stack layout, which is very compiler-specific. Again, if you're expecting C to fail when you trigger undefined behaviour, then you're in for a nasty surprise. C can do anything the hell it wants once you've triggered undefined behaviour. This includes being inconsistent.

Comment: @nneonneo: I am totally agree with you that it is **not functional** and what if I will run this on a different compiler? And I am going to study more about it.

Answer (score 4):

`LEN` is 2, which is enough to store both digits but not the required null terminating character.  You are therefore overrunning the arrays (and the heap allocations, in that version of the code!) and this causes *undefined behavior*.  The fact that one works and the other does not is simply a byproduct of how the undefined behavior plays out on your particular system; the malloc version could indeed crash on a different system or a different compiler.

Correct results, incorrect results, crashing, or something completely different are all possibilities when you invoke undefined behavior.

Change `LEN` to 3 and your example input would work fine.

I would suggest indicating the size of your buffers in your `scanf()` line to avoid the undefined behavior.  You may get incorrect results, but your program at least would not crash or have a security vulnerability:

```
scanf("%2s", num1);
```

Note that the number you use there must be one less than the size of the array -- in this example it assumes an array of size 3 (so you read a maximum of 2 characters, because you need the last character for the null terminating character).

Comment: but whenever we define normal array like this `arr[10]` and give `10` values then here why we don't think about  last character for the null terminating character. And it works fine here.

Comment: Doing `scanf("%2s", num1);` is good, but it still leaves a pitfall ... if the person enters `123 <return>`, then it puts `1` and `2` and `\0` in num1, BUT it leaves the `3` (and the newline from return) sitting out there for whatever your next read is to grab -- probably causing a mysterious misfunction.

Comment: @JohnHascall Indeed -- still, at least that behavior is defined, which is a step forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not "work fine" (and should not "work fine") with either explicitly declared arrays or `malloc`-ed arrays. Strings like `15` and `12` require `char` buffers of size `3` at least. You provided buffers of size `2`. Your program overruns the buffer boundary in both cases, thus causing undefined behavior. It is just that the consequences of that undefined behavior manifest themselves differently in different versions of the code.

The `malloc` version has a greater chance to produce illusion of "working" since sizes of dynamically allocated memory blocks are typically rounded to the nearest implementation-depended "round" boundary (like `8` or `16` bytes). That means that your `malloc` calls actually allocate more memory than you ask them to. This might temporarily hide the buffer overrun problems present in your code. This produces the illusion of your program "working fine".

Meanwhile, the version with explicit arrays uses local arrays. Local arrays often have precise size (as declared) and also have a greater chance to end up located next to each other in memory. This means that buffer overrun in one array can easily destroy the contents of the other array. This is exactly what happened in your case.

However, even in the `malloc`-based version I'd still expect a good debugging version of standard library implementation to catch the overrun problems. It is quite possible that if you attempt to actually `free` these `malloc`-ed memory blocks (something you apparently didn't bother to do), `free` will notice the problem and tell you that heap integrity has been violated at some point after `malloc`.

P.S. Don't use `atoi` to convert strings to integers. Function that converts strings to integers is called `strtol`.

Comment: but why it is accepting second variable `12`. It should not accept both the values.

Comment: @SachinPanwar: while it would be great fun to analyze, in depth, why your program appears to work, this is one of those cases where you should seriously accept that your program is simply **not functional**. You can trace the program instruction-by-instruction if you really want to know why something works or doesn't on your particular computer and particular operating environment. (Seriously, undefined behaviours really are environment-dependent).

Comment: @SachinPanwar: There's no such thing as "should accept" and "shouldn't accept" in this case. The behavior is undefined. Anything can happen. Any deterministic expectations, like your "shouldn't accept both values", make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreyT: I got your point. But what is the specific reason behind this undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Sachin Panwar: The specific reason is that content of one string went out of bounds and overwrote the content of another string. The string that was read later "won" (it appears to be intact), while the string that was read first "lost" (got overwritten).